# Stage.show() changes value of ComboBox

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, stage

Consider the following MCVE. Of course, the functionality of this MCVE is completely pointless, but I need it to work this way in the real implementation.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

@SuppressWarnings("all")
public class MCVE extends Application {

    private static final String OPTION_1 = "Option 1 (www.option1.com)";
    private static final String OPTION_2 = "Option 2 (www.option2.com)";
    private static final String OPTION_3 = "Option 3 (www.option3.com)";
    private static final String OPTION_4 = "Option 4 (www.option4.com)";
    private static final String OPTION_5 = "Option 5 (www.option5.com)";

    ComboBox<String> cb;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        VBox outer = new VBox();

        cb = new ComboBox<String>();
        outer.getChildren().add(cb);

        Scene scene = new Scene(outer, 640, 480);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() {
                cb.getItems().addAll(OPTION_1, OPTION_2, OPTION_3, OPTION_4, OPTION_5);
                cb.setEditable(true);

                // Adds a listener to the selectedItemProperty that gets the
                // value inside the parenthesis of the selected item and sets
                // this as the text of the ComboBox.
                cb.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                    String[] valSplit = newValue.split("[\\(\\)]");
                    if (valSplit.length > 1) {
                        Platform.runLater(() -> cb.getEditor().setText(valSplit[1]));
                    }
                });

                cb.getEditor().textProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                    System.out.println("CB value: " + newValue);
                });

                setURL("www.option2.com");

                return null;
            }
        };

        task.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
            primaryStage.show();
        });

        new Thread(task).start();
    }

    public void setURL(String url) {
        // First we check if the classValue is the URL of one of the options in
        // the ComboBox. If it is we select that option.
        for (String option : cb.getItems()) {
            // We retrieve the URL of the option.
            String opURL = option.split("[\\(\\)]")[1];
            // If the URL of the option is equals to the provided URL, we select
            // this option and break the for loop.
            if (opURL.equals(url)) {
                cb.getSelectionModel().select(option);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Since I invoke `setURL("www.option2.com")`, I expect it to first select the option in the `ComboBox` with that URL, and then get the value inside the parenthesis and set that as the text of the `ComboBox`. So I except the final value of the `ComboBox` to be "www.option2.com". But this doesn't happen. Instead the final value is "Option 2 (www.option2.com)".

Since I have added a listener to the `textProperty` of the `ComboBox`, I can see that the value is first the expected "www.option2.com", but then changes back to "Option 2 (www.option2.com)". After some further investigation, I've found out that it's the invocation of `primaryStage.show()` that changes the value. More specifically, it's the invocation of the deprecated `Parent.impl_processCSS` that changes the value.

So if I set the URL after `primaryStage.show()`, everything works as I except. But if I want to do all of the work before I show the dialog, like I do now, it doesn't.

So why does `primaryStage.show()` change the value of my `ComboBox`, and how can I prevent this? Should I maybe use another approach when trying to set the value of a `ComboBox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could exchange the part of you code which sets the text of the [editor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#editorProperty) of the `ComboBox` with some code that sets up a [cell factory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#cellFactoryProperty--) and a [converter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#converterProperty--).

```
cb.setConverter(new StringConverter<String>(){
    @Override
    public String toString(String object) {
        if(object != null) {
            String[] valSplit = object.split("[\\(\\)]");
            return valSplit[1];
        } else 
            return null;

    }

    @Override
    public String fromString(String string) {

        List<String> collect = cb.getItems().stream().filter(s -> s.contains(string)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        if(collect.size() == 1)
            return collect.get(0);
        else
            return null;
    }
});

cb.setCellFactory(item -> {
    return new ListCell<String>(){
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if(item == null || empty)
                setText("");
            else
                setText(item);
        }
    };
});
```

The `toString` method of your converter will format the selected item in the needed form, and the cell factory ensures that the items in the drop down list are displayed in the original format.

**Note:** I have also filled the `fromString` method of the converter. This method is executed, when the user types into the editor then presses `enter`. This implementation checks all the items in the list, and if there is only one single item which contains the typed string, that item will be selected.